# How to use IEnumererate to insert a value into the commandargument of a button?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Using IEnumererate to insert a value into the CommandArgument of a button

```
<%foreach (GoDating.Models.Dates dates in getofferDetails()){%>
```

How can I assign a value `dates.id` for the command argument of a button ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe standard way will be work

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" Text="Text" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%= dates.id %>' />
```

Comment: No the command argument is jut seen as a string. The value for the command argument is "<%= dates.id %>"

Comment: Try to use dates.id.ToString() insted of dates.id :)

Comment: Doesn't work. I reckon you can't have ASP inside ASP

Comment: Try to use (string)dates.id instead of dates.id :)

Comment: Whatever I put into the command argument outputs as a string [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/pry4ZzJ.png)

Comment: Try to use ((string)dates.id) or (dates.id as string) instead of dates.id
Maybe it is displayed to you as string but work as you need?